# TreeView becomes unresponsive on 64 bit win7 but works on windows XP

Tags: treeview, 32bit-64bit, windows-forms-designer

In a Windows form application developed using Visual studio 2008 (.Net 3.5), for all three - x64 build, x86 build, Any CPU: TreeView becomes unresponsive on 64 bit win7 as the number of nodes increase (say 2000+). It stops recognizing mouse clicks, though the arrow keys work to expand or collapse the nodes.
The same application (x86 build and Any CPU build) works perfectly fine on Win XP (sp3).

Any clues to why it is so?

Comment: Are you using VB.Net or C#? Also please share the code that you are using to generate the treeview.

Comment: It depends on how much memory is available on the box. Can you inspect how much memory is available in both the Operating System ? GDI does not support Virtualization which has been a popular term nowadays. Did you use OnDemand loading of treeview nodes ?

Comment: @Abhishek - There is a lot of memory available, I run it on a 4 GB machine and I check it to find that there still is a lot of it available while the exe is running. What is OnDemand loading? If that means adding nodes on the run then yes but problem appear even before I add any new node.

Comment: @Siddharth - It's C#, and it's too much of a code to share.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of the cause of your problem. It maybe some problem with the TreeView control itself or something else.

But I can suggest a possible solution for it. We had to do this for a couple of our projects.

Since you know that it works fine on 32-bit Operating Systems, just force your EXE to run in 32-bit mode (until you find a good solution/replacement for your problems). To do this you will need to use the `CorFlags Conversion Tool` that comes with .NET framework 2.0 and later.

After building your project, run the following command from the Visual Studio Command Prompt:

`CorFlags.exe "C:\YourProject\bin\Release\YourExecutable.exe" /32BIT+`
(replace path & filename as necessary).

Then try running your EXE again and reproducing the problem, and see if the problem is gone.

The following articles may probably help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. However, it didn't work. And, is it really different from creating an x86 build or using Troubleshoot compatability option that Win 7 offers?

Comment: yes it is different. What problem did you face after this? Exactly same or something changed?

Comment: Okay. The probem stayed the way it was.